# App Breaking in main.m - suspected retaining issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my app appears to be breaking in main.m on a line with contents:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

What does that line do, and why could it cause a breakpoint to fail?

Is this a memory issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a function as you know it, it never actually returns - see [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain). Chances are very good you do have a memory issue if all the debugger shows you is a problem there, or else the app is trying to load a bad nib?

Have you tried building with the analyzer (in Snow Leopard only, shift-command-A kicks it off). Chances are it will show you something of concern